# Excel VBA Run-Time error 13

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

THIS IS AN UPDATE TO MY ORIGINAL QUESTION OF 12/5.  IT INCLUDES THE COMPLETE CODE USED FOR THE WORKBOOK.

MANY, MANY THANKS.!!!

I created a form that has 3 text boxes for data entry.  It also has 3 buttons to choose from after data entry.  The below code populates the table with the information from the form plus some additional information from the header in the worksheet when an "Update" button is pressed. This worked fine until I entered the code line " Reg1.SetFocus".  I did this to set the focus back to the first text box after pressing the update button.  I now get "Run-Time error 13" that debugs to this line of code:

".Reg4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Reg1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 4, 0)"

This all goes away if I delete the "Reg1.SetFocus" line in the prior sub.

The complete code for the workbook is:

```
Option Explicit

   'Private Sub AmountEntry_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    AmountEntry.Value = Format(AmountEntry.Value, "$#,#00.00")
End Sub

Private Sub AmountEntry_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click()
   Dim Ctrl As MSForms.Control
F   or Each Ctrl In Input_Form.Controls

    Select Case TypeName(Ctrl)

        Case "TextBox"
            Ctrl.Text = ""

        Case "OptionButton"
            Ctrl.Value = False

        Case "ComboBox"
            Ctrl.ListIndex = -1

    End Select

   Next Ctrl

   'DateSelect.Value = Date

End Sub

Private Sub CloseButton_Click()
   Unload Input_Form
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateTableButton_Click()
   Dim LastRow As Range
   Dim AssistanceTable As ListObject

'Add row to bottom of Assistance table
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Assistance").ListRows.Add

 'Enter data from form into our new row
  Set AssistanceTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Assistance")
  Set LastRow = AssistanceTable.ListRows(AssistanceTable.ListRows.Count).Range

With LastRow
    .Cells(1, 1) = Range("fund").Value
    .Cells(1, 2) = Reg1.Value
    .Cells(1, 3) = Reg2.Value
    .Cells(1, 4) = Range("mass_date").Value
    .Cells(1, 5) = Reg3.Value
    .Cells(1, 6) = Range("mass_time").Value

 End With

  Dim Ctrl As MSForms.Control

For Each Ctrl In Input_Form.Controls

    Select Case TypeName(Ctrl)

        Case "TextBox"
            Ctrl.Text = ""

        Case "OptionButton"
            Ctrl.Value = False

        Case "ComboBox"
            Ctrl.ListIndex = -1

    End Select

  'Set focus to Parishioner ID
  On Error Resume Next
  Reg1.SetFocus
  On Error GoTo 0
  Next Ctrl

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateTableButton_Enter()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Reg1_AfterUpdate()
   'Check to see if value exists
   If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("a:a"), Me.Reg1.Value) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "Parishioner not yet in database"
   Me.Reg1.Value = ""
   Exit Sub
   End If
   'Lookup values based on first control
   With Me.Reg4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Reg1),       Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 4, 0)
   End With
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
  Range("b3").Value = Format(Me.ComboBox2.Value, "dd mmm,yyyy")
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Me.Reg3.AddItem "Check"
   Me.Reg3.AddItem "Cash"

End Sub
```

Comment: `VLookup(CLng(Me.Reg1),)` is a compile error and it looks like some lines got run together there at the end.  Is that a copy\paste error?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the real code.

Comment: Hi.  Not sure what you mean "real code".  This is the code cut/paste.  Sorry but I am a novice and new to this site.